# header opacity not changing when scrolling down

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the header to change opacity when scrolling down the page (but when it's at the top, the opacity needs to be 100%). I've tried changing the javascript but I cannot get it to work. I think the problem is maybe it doesn't reference the 'header-wrap' div correctly.

Any suggestions?

```js
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
});
```

```css
body{
height:1000px;
}



/* Header */
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
 background:#CC0;/* delete */
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.6;
}
#header-top{
 /* contains logo & title text */
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
 padding:10px 0 10px 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-top-content-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-text-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 /* The below apparently makes the text (all lines) justified, but not in safari */
 text-align-last:right;
 -moz-text-align-last: justify; /* For Firefox */
}
.header-logo-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 padding-right:48px; /* changed from 50px for web safe reasons e.g. if one browser displays a larger font than another then it may cause the width to exceed 960px - could change back if logo is narrower */
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
#header-right-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
}
.header-navigation-link{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 48px; /* changed from 50px for web safe reasons e.g. if one browser displays a larger font than another then it may cause the width to exceed 960px - could change back if logo is narrower */
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 color:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header-top">
    <div class="header-top-content-wrap">
      <div class="header-logo-wrap"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="95" height="50"  alt="logo"/></div>
      <div class="header-text-wrap">
        <header>Business title name here</header>
        <slogan>slogan text here</slogan>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right-wrap">
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Services</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">About</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learn to use your browsers debug tools!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was you used `-` in a js variable..

Try this:

```js
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
 background:#CC0;/* delete */
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: your answer works in principle but I cannot get it to work for my site - I've now added the entire source code of the header. why does your solution work for the small demo you made but not for my site?

Comment: Well for one thing you don't have any scroll.. Try adding `body { height:2500px;}`  to your css, just for the test. then scroll and see if it works.
If not please check:
1) did you include jquery?
2) Open debug tools (F12) then go to 'Console' and see if there are any errors. If so please post them here.

Comment: @user3760941 see my comment above

Comment: I havent included jquery. The error console in safari shows it cannot find variable '$' in the line var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap'); - but I'm thinking that your code is correct and that I added the script into the html section (as well as the full script in the head section) in the wrong place and don't know where to put it

Comment: @user3760941 As I said in my answer you need jQuery. Please add this to the top of your `<head>` and try again: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I've always build websites using html css and basic javascript before. If I add that line of code ‘<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jqu‌​ery.min.js"></script‌​>’ before the other script (in the head), it shows a syntax error and ‘code hinting may not work’ message. If I add just the script src into the other script, the debug shows this error: ‘Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404)’

Comment: @user3760941 Yes but your code refrences jQuery (e.g. $) so if you want that to work you must load jquery. Please edit your question to include the  HTML file you have after you added the above jquery script to the head. I will help you fix it

Comment: Sorry but I don’t know how to attach the html file - but I think the jQuery is successfully added now because it shows a separate jQuery.min.js window. I have edited the post at the top though with the code, and it doesn’t change the opacity when scrolling down

Comment: @user3760941 Your'e probably just missing something.. Here test this fully compiled HTML i made of your code. This works.. Save it as html and open it with browser. http://pastebin.com/raw/Y9Ebjqiw

Comment: you're absolutely right - I didn't put the actual script in the html section. it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is not valid:

```
var header-wrap = $('#header-wrap');
```

You are not allowed to use `-` char for an identifier name.

You can use camelcase instead:

```
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
```

In the future, you should look in your browser's JS console (open debug tools - F12 in most browsers) to check for errors - in this case you would get a pretty self-explanatory error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable name, because using `-` in variable name throws syntax error.

```
 var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   headerWrap .addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
   if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
     headerWrap .removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
   }
 });
```